# User agent StyleSheet is overriding my text color messing up my hover effect

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I set up a few button classes to style the couple buttons I have within my pages. They work perfectly on the a tags I have them on right now, but when I attempted to add them to an input with the type of submit the text color is being pulled from the user agent stylesheet. I attempted to just force the color into the input which did work but then the hover effect won't fire for the text color. The rest of the hover works fine but the color refuses to change.

```css
html, 
body {
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1.2rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-outline {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #a8a6a1;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline">
```

I mean I'm sure I can just write more css and repeat what I have coded for the buttons but that feels so redundant since it works for others but not here. The user agent Stylesheet being used is input[type="submit" i], I read somewhere about just writing my own css inside of a selector with that but once again it would be purely redundant it seems like. Just really confused as to why it is doing this for me. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Do I get this right: Your 'Problem' is, that you don't want to add a `color` declaration to `.btn` because you feel like the declaration on `body` _should_  work?

Comment: You wrote '.btn:hover { color: #000}' and it works. It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Wow, this got me thinking here and I just figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out now. I forgot that I had set the a tag color, so I just had to go add the input tag and set the color to white there too. For some reason setting the color to white within something like

```
.contact form input[type="submit"] {
    color: #fff;
}
```

wouldn't trigger the hover for the text color properly (no change) so I added this instead

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    color: #fff;
}
```